# Implementation of virtual functions from a third party class

Tags: c++, function, class, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

**Summary**
I want to design a class which will hold all my problem data so that its member functions can be used to pass information to the third party member functions. How can I do it for the below two functions?

**My Problem:**

I'm coding a program for scientific computation. To solve my problem I have to use some third party libraries. Currently I'm using Ipopt (for numerical optimization).

To use Ipopt, I have to provide enough information in the following way.
First I need to create a class which should inherit the third party class TNLP.
Then I have to provide implementation to the 8 virtual functions, of which two of them is as below with its implementation.

```
// MyNLP is the class which I coded to inherit from TNLP.
bool MyNLP::get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, Number* x,
                           bool init_z, Number* z_L, Number* z_U,
                           Index m, bool init_lambda,
                           Number* lambda)
{
   // Here, we assume we only have starting values for x, if you code
   // your own NLP, you can provide starting values for the others if
   // you wish.
    assert(init_x == true);
    assert(init_z == false);
    assert(init_lambda == false);

   // we initialize x in bounds, in the upper right quadrant
    x[0]=0.5;
    x[1]=1.5;
    return true;
}
```

and

```
bool MyNLP::eval_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number& 
obj_value)
{
    // return the value of the objective function
   Number x2 = x[1];
   obj_value = -(x2 - 2.0) * (x2 - 2.0);
   return true;
}
```

In the above implementations I've provided values to the parameters within the function call directly. Now to make the program more general, instead of directly entering the required information in the above functions, I wish to use a class which contain all the information regarding my problem and use function members in the third party virtual function.

For example, if `NLP` is the class which hold my problem content and `m_nlp` is its incident in the class `MyNLP` then I'll rewrite the virtual functions as below.

```
bool MyNLP::get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, Number* x,
                           bool init_z, Number* z_L, Number* z_U,
                           Index m, bool init_lambda,
                           Number* lambda)
{
   // Here, we assume we only have starting values for x, if you code
   // your own NLP, you can provide starting values for the others if
   // you wish.
    assert(init_x == true);
    assert(init_z == false);
    assert(init_lambda == false);

    x = m_nlp->get_initial_values();

}
```

and

```
bool MyNLP::eval_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number& 
obj_value)
{
    // return the value of the objective function
    obj_value = m_nlp->get_obj_value();
}
```

But I cannot do this in the above fashion, since  second function uses `x` to calculate `object_val`. How can I design a class to hold all the data and uses its member functions to give required information to Ipopt.

**What I thought as a solution:**

define a `std::vector<Number> values` as a member of `nlp` class and point the `x` to the first element of the `values`.

```
 x = &(m_nlp->get_values()).at(0);
```

in the second function, I can modify `values` instead of `x` and calculate `obj_val`.

Comment: I dont understand "In the above implementations I've provided values to the parameters within the function call directly." (and anything beyond that). With "function parameters" do you mean `x[0] =0.5` ? I dont really understand the question. I mean it is your class, just get the parameters from whereever you like, eg `x[0]= this->getX0()`

Comment: @tobi303, `x` and other parameters are defined in the third party class. But I've to provide values to it. I'm seeking a generalized way to give values to it

Comment: seems like the generalized way is to override their virtual methods. I dont understand why you need something on top of that

Comment: @tobi303, my problem can be solved by different numerical optimization algorithms. Ipopt is one algorithm but there are others. I'm designing a class which holds contents of my problems (i.e variables and methods) so that I can use this general class with different library packages

Answer (score 1):

You could derive a class from MyNLP.  Or

```
class NLPWithStuff : public MyNLP {
   //... 
   virtual bool get_starting_point(/*...*/) 
    {
        // optional boost::signals that do their stuff ??
        // do my stuff, set flags so that no-one touches my stuff 
        // don't assert

        return MyNLP::get_starting_point(/*.+.*/);
    }
};
```

You'll have to declare `MyNLP::get_starting_point` `virtual` to make it work.

Comment: I hope it's some useful information for me. But I'm a beginner and could you please elaborate it?

Comment: So, NLPWithStuff inherit from MyNLP and MyNLP inherit from TNLP.  Implementation of MyNLP functions are provided in NLPWithStuff. Isn't it?

Comment: No. the derived class provides extra capabilities, but lets other classes in the hierarchy do their own stuff, or can override them. MyNLP is still responsible for doing what it knows to do.